# If statement within switch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know I'm just thinking of the logic all wrong here but how do I achieve the following:

```
update @table   
             set   column1 = case 
               when column1 <> '' 
                   then rtrim(column1) + ', ' + rtrim(column2)--if statement here 
               else     rtrim(column2)              
               end
            from @othertable
```

I basically want to check if rtrim(column 2) = 'value' then replace it with something else.  I understand this is within a switch statement, so how would this be acheived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  update @table   
         set   column1 = case 
           when column1 <> '' 
               then rtrim(column1) + ', ' + 
              case 
              when column2 = 'value' 
                 then rtrim(column2) 
              else ... 
              end
           else  rtrim(column2)              
           end
        from @othertable
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you don't need any switch and if clause:

```
update @table set column1 = rtrim(isnull(nullif(column1,'') + ', ', '')) + rtrim(column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `REPLACE` within your `CASE` statement

eg: `REPLACE(rtrim(column2),'value','newValue');`

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) for more details on REPLACE